# How can I find current in this Ward-Leonard system?

Tags: current, dc, electric-machine

I was able to find only RPM in this question. How can I find the armature current?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should compute the current as a difference of voltage potentials.

Full load current = 5kW/250V=20A

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftPP4B.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>